# Extract a nested data frame from a data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following three data.frames wrapped in a data.table:

```
name <- data.frame(c("Bob","Mary","Jane","Kim"))
weight <- data.frame(c(60,65,45,55))
height <- data.frame(c(170,165,140,135))
dft <- data.table( x = list(name,weight,height) )
```

I want to know how to extract a data.frame from `dft`? For example, for `name`, I can use

```
dft[[1, "x"]]
```

but it's not very efficient. Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` solution can extract all data frames by splitting each row into a separate data frame and then unnesting.

```
library(dplyr)
dft %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  group_split(x) %>% 
  lapply(., function(z) unnest(z, x))
```

Also, I would advise caution in unnamed column names in your nested data frames.

Answer (score 0):

To extract one dataframe from `x` you can refer them by index.

```
dft$x[[1]]

#  name
#1  Bob
#2 Mary
#3 Jane
#4  Kim
```

To extract all of them together

```
dft$x

# [[1]]
#  name
#1  Bob
#2 Mary
#3 Jane
#4  Kim

#[[2]]
#  weight
#1     60
#2     65
#3     45
#4     55

#[[3]]
#  height
#1    170
#2    165
#3    140
#4    135
```

To combine them into one :

```
do.call(cbind, dft$x)

#  name weight height
#1  Bob     60    170
#2 Mary     65    165
#3 Jane     45    140
#4  Kim     55    135
```

**data**

```
library(data.table)

name <- data.frame(name = c("Bob","Mary","Jane","Kim"))
weight <- data.frame(weight = c(60,65,45,55))
height <- data.frame(height = c(170,165,140,135))
dft <- data.table( x = list(name,weight,height))
```